# javascript random overflow or out of range

Tags: javascript

I used the `Math.random()` function to generate a number as recommended by this W3School's example:

```
Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
```

The example description said it'd "Return a random number between 1 and 10"

I slightly modified it to get a range between 2 and 17:

```
Math.floor((Math.random() * 17) + 2);
```

However, when I used the console to test it, I got the value 18.

Why is my code returning an value outside of the expected range?

Comment: if math random is .999 times 17 that will be 16 floored.  Add 2 to that and you get 18

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
//exclude max
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

//include max
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min +1)) + min;
}
```

Source : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Math/random

Comment: should use ceiling if max is included?

Comment: In same page, you have example to include : max return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min +1)) + min;

Comment: reminder for others: directly using ceil() is not corrent as it would not including the min

Comment: you can include the max value just by replacing the `.floor` with `.round` instead of adding 1

Answer (score 8):

[`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) returns a value of [0,1) (upper limit non-inclusive!). If you multiply that by 17, you get a value between 0 and 17 ( [0, 17) ). Add 2 to that and your range is between 2 and 19 ( [2,19) ), so 18 is right inside that range.

```
Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
```

Returns a range of [1,10] because if you multiple [0,1) by 10, you get [0,10), add 1 and you get [1, 11), and with floor it's [1,10].

Comment: [Math.random() documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

Answer (score 1):

You are adding 2 to the result of Math.floor(Math.random()*17).  So for example, if you have a floored result of 16 from this (.999 * 17), 2 gets added, resulting in 18.

Answer (score 1):

The math.random() function returns values between [0,1>; that is: a value less than 1.0000000. If you multiply this by 10 and then add 1 (from W3Schools) you get a number from 1 to 10 (inclusive).
You multiply by 17 and then add 2, so you get a number from 2 to 18 (inclusive).