# Send random quote with tweet button click in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing a "Random Quote Machine" which takes random quotes from and stored array and let the user tweet it. I have created the random quote generator but not able to tweet the same. Need some help with tweet button.

**My Jquery**

```
var quote = new Array()
quote[0] = 'this is first quote'
quote[1] = 'this is second quote'

function tweet() {
window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?hashtags= freecodecamp&text='   + encodeURIComponent($(".message").html(quote[randomquote]));
}


$(document).ready(function() {
$("#getMessage").on("click", function(){
  var randomquote = Math.floor(Math.random()*(quote.length-1));      
  $(".message").html(quote[randomquote]);      
});

$('#twitter-share-button').on('click', tweet)

})
```

### Bit of html

```
<div class = "col-xs-12 well message">
  <h3>Click to get Random Quotes</h3>
</div>
<button id = "tweetMessage" class = "btn btn-default btn-lg" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw"></i> Tweet it</button>
<button id = "getMessage" class = "btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-fire fa-fw"></i> Get Quote</button>
```

Comment: var quote = new Array() quote[0] = 'this is first quote' quote[1] = 'this is second quote'

Comment: `var quotes = ['this is first quote', 'this is second quote']`

Comment: At least 5 missing ; and to get random value you can see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35606334/javascript-random-overflow-or-out-of-range/35606413#35606413 or https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Math/random

Comment: By the way, it seems like you're actually getting a good answer here but keep in mind that this sort of question bears the risk of being closed as too localized. SO is not just a Q&A site but is about building up a knowledgebase of questions and answers. Frankly, nobody else is ever going to have this exact same question. If you know this however, there is almost always a way to rewrite the question where it might be useful to others down the line.

Answer (score 4):

```
  $('#twitter-share-button').on('click', tweet)
```

You don't have an element with `id="twitter-share-button"`

Also don't subtract 1 when getting random. Since you're doing `Math.floor` and since `Math.random` never returns exactly `1`, it will never hit the upperbound.

Also your `randomquote` variable is used inside of the `tweet` function but exists only inside your `document.ready` block. You need to figure out a way to pass it in. What would make even more sense is to pass in the message itself rather than the index.

Also for text you should use `.text(...)` instead of `.html(...)` as that will help with security (look up cross-site-scripting if you are interested).

I see that you're doing freecodecamp. Cool and keep it up!

Comment: Thanks a ton. It going to twitter now. Below is my codepen.

http://codepen.io/nabendu82/pen/GZRaQw

One little problem though, it is tweeting html characters in the tweet because my quotes contains it.

Comment: So remove the quotes from your tweets?

Answer (score 1):

Got it finally.
    var quote = new Array()
    quote[0] = '

#### "There\'s a difference between a philosophy and a bumper sticker."
-Charles M. Schulz

'

```
function tweet(message) {
window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?hashtags= freecodecamp&text='   + encodeURIComponent(message));
}

var msg;
function tweetHandler() {
tweet($(msg).text()); 

}
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#getMessage").on("click", function(){
var randomquote = Math.floor(Math.random()*(quote.length-1));
msg = quote[randomquote];
$(".message").html(msg);
});

$('#tweetMessage').on('click', tweetHandler);

});
```

My whole code at

http://codepen.io/nabendu82/full/GZRaQw/